# Resizable responsive toggle iframes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dom

I need a layout with 2 IFRAMEs which on a screen can be toggled by javascript without refreshing the contents (they are just changing position), and columns can be resized.
On a mobile they should be 100% width stacked.

[Drawing example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1keD.png)

https://codepen.io/az3l10/pen/vYgVmeP

```js
function toggleLayout() {
  document.querySelector('main').classList.toggle('social');
 
}
```

```css
main div {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 400px);
  height: 100%
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;
}

[orange] {
  position:absolute;
  right:0px;
  background-color: #FFAD77;
}

[yellow] {
    position: absolute;
  background-color: #FFE377;
  width:400px;
  height:30px;
  left:calc(100% - 400px);
}


[green] {
    position: absolute;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  width:400px;
  height:300px;
  left:calc(100% - 400px);
  top:30px;
}


[purple] {
  position: absolute;
  width:400px;
  height:calc(100% - 330px);

  left:calc(100% - 400px);
  top:330px;
  background-color: #FF77C8;
  
}

main.social div {
 
}



main.social [orange] {
 left:calc(100% - 400px);
 top:30px;
  width:400px;
  height:1000px;

  background-color: #FFE377;
  
  
}


main.social [green] {
 position: absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width: calc(100% - 400px);
 height: calc(100%);
 
  background-color: lightgreen;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 1580px) {

[orange] {
  position:relative;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
  width:100%;
  background-color: #FFAD77;
}

[yellow] {
  position:relative;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
  width:100%;
  background-color: #FFE377;
}

[purple] {
  position:relative;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:600px;
    background-color: #FF77C8;
  }

[green] {
  position:relative;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:10px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
   
}


main.social.sociald {
  height:600px;
}


main.social.chatd {
  height:10px;
}

}
```

```html
<main>
 <div orange> 
ORANGE
  </div>

    <div yellow>

        <button onclick="toggleLayout">TOGGLE</button>

        
    </div>

    <div green id="sociald">    
    <figure style="width:100%;height:100%;margin:0px">
        <iframe id="framesoc" border=0 style="width:100%;height:100%" src="https://www.google.com"></iframe>
        </figure>
    
    </div>

    <div purple id="chatd"> 
        
        <figure style="width:100%;height:100%;margin:0px">
        <iframe id="framechat" border=0 style="width:100%;height:100%" src="https://www.calm.com/breathe"></iframe>
        </figure>
        
    </div>

</main>

 
</body>
</html>
```

The issue I have is that since DIV position is absolute i can't resize the columns, and if i change the positioning i cannot toggle.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: What did you tried ? where is your code ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately it seems you have misunderstood how it works. It is not a free code writing service where you just post a requirement. It is expected you post your code attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected. See [ask] and [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Don't use absolute positioning if it can be achieved using [CSS Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) or [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

## Mobile-first

We know we want two elements, A and B, to be on our site, and that those two belong together. That means, we create two elements wrapped in a grouping element:

```css
/* Ignore; for demonstration-purposes */
html {height:100%}
body {margin:0;min-height:100%}
#a, #b {min-width:100px;min-height:100px}
#a {background-color:red}
#b {background-color:blue}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="a"></div>
  <div id="b"></div>
</div>
```

With the two having (intrinsically) `display: block` set, the default CSS suffices, so no need to write any.

Now, when the site is viewed on a larger screen, we want there to be...:

- ... a 2-by-2 grid
- ... a toggle-button (simply: a single checkbox) in the grid's upper-right corner, to swap A and B's positions
- ... the first ("selected") element to take up the whole first column

We modify the HTML to fit our desired result, and start writing the CSS.
We basically disable the large-screen-only elements, and (re-)enable them and other wanted styles in a `@media`-rule. Also, we add the grid, and give `#a` the `selected`-class by default.

Now, to add the swapping, functionality, we need some JavaScript.
We want to add the `selected`-class to either A or B, depending on the checkboxes `checked`-property.

All in all, the code could now look like this:

```js
const a = document.querySelector('#a');
const b = document.querySelector('#b');
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('click', evt => {
  if (evt.target.checked) {
    b.classList.add('selected');
    a.classList.remove('selected');
  } else {
    a.classList.add('selected');
    b.classList.remove('selected');
  }
});

/* Alternatively (same effect)
const wrapperElements = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper>*:not(label)');
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('click', evt => {
  let i = Number(!!evt.target.checked);
  wrapperElements[i].classList.add('selected');
  wrapperElements[++i % 2].classList.remove('selected');
});
*/
```

```css
/* Ignore; for demonstration-purposes */
html {height:100%}
body {margin:0;min-height:100%}
#a, #b {min-width:100px;min-height:100px}
#a {background-color:red}
#b {background-color:blue}

/* The CSS */
label {display: none}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) { /* When at least 768px, then: */
  .wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
  }
  label {
    display: initial;
    grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
  }
  .selected {grid-area: 1 / 1 / -1 / 1}
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <label><input type="checkbox">Toggle A/B</label>
  
  <div id="a" class="selected"></div>
  <div id="b"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great!!! I think now i can add the column resizing by myself. thanks really appreciated!